# Running shoes for walking?

Tags: shoes

I've never really paid heed to the fact that there are different shoes for running, walking and training in the gym.. I used to just walk into a store, try on a few pairs and brought whatever felt the most comfortable.. I don't go out for runs, but am planning to start, but I have a habit of walking. I'm thinking about getting a new pair of shoes. Being a student, I need to consider the durability of the shoes that I'd be buying, too. Is there a way to tell which shoes will "last" longer for me? I'm a 180 cm, ~70-75kg male.

I am of the belief that running shoes will last longer, simply because they have a sole that's made to take more impact, but again, I also see that they're lighter and being light, the wear will (probably) be higher and hence will make the life shorter..

I have owned shoes from multiple brands, and they have fared differently. A pair of Woodland trekking shoes wore out from the inside (heel region) within a month because of the copious amounts of perspiration that my feet let out. I've owned a pair of Puma IDP running shoes which lasted for about two years of more or less regular use (just walking around) before the outsole simply came off. I've owned a pair of "trainers" by Fila, which lasted only a couple of months before the soles were absolutely flat, flat to the degree that I struggled for grip even on average surfaces..

So, is there a way for me to understand which shoe will be more durable than the other? I don't buy too many shoes, and whatever shoe I buy, I wear it around with almost everything... Be it casual shorts or jeans..

P. S. I've never had problems with foot pain due to shoes without manufacturing defects, not even if I walk in just slippers for a good 20 kilometres.

Answer (score 1):

I think the main difference is running shoes are built to handle and absorb, short- and long-term, the much greater impact that comes with running.

While using "walking" shoes for serious running is probably not recommended, the reverse would not be true.

> Can running shoes be used as walking shoes?
>
> The short answer: yes.
>
> Running shoes and walking shoes have similar qualities that make them ideal for being active. While running shoes are designed to be durable for the rigorous demands of running, they are excellent as walking shoes, too.

[Fleet Feet: Running shoes for walking](https://www.fleetfeet.com/how-to-start-running/running-shoes-for-walking)

Answer (score 0):

I really like "On Cloud" brand shoe, Swiss made.  On their website, you can actually answer questions on your shoe use to help find the best model or models for you.  I have been using these for weight training and jogging for about 4 years now and really like them. Good luck!